# How do I create a word document in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word

I'm attempting to create a word document from inside my rails app. 
I gave the htmltoword gem a go and it's close to working.

Where it falls down.  If I have a spelling mistake in the content, and open the document generated, word doesn't highlight the mistake. Word also doesn't find the mistake when I do a manual spell check.

I think it might have to do with "compatibility mode", but I'm not sure.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way to make a "true" word doc.

I'm also wondering if anyone has see this behaviour and corrected for it. I need spelling to work.

Comment: There are a lot of gems https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=✓&query=docx, most used one seems to be docx gem.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [htmltoword gem source](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword)...It looks like they set the `proofState` to `clean` by default...

In the source code, `templates/default/word/settings.xml` has this line that "Gets or sets the state of the spelling checker in this document."...

`<w:proofState w:spelling="clean" w:grammar="clean"/>`

It has two possible values...`clean` (the default) or `dirty` (which seems to be what you want).

So, you can either modify the config (maybe [this](https://github.com/karnov/htmltoword#configure-templates-and-xslt-paths) will help) or use your own cloned version of the gem if there is no way to modify this.

Comment: Awesome.. I'll give that a go.

Comment: I forked the gem.. that change didn't do it. I still have no spelling mistakes.. And trusd me there are some.